# SSRS selecting results based on comma delimited list

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table that stores IDs as INT, for example Table A:

```
|  ID  |  Name
   1       A
   2       B
   3       C
```

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID IN (@ID)
```

This variable @ID will be coming from a comma separated list on the input parameter section in SSRS. The input will be something like 1,2,3

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try without the single quotes

Comment: When inputting into SSRS, this is without the quotes

Comment: Are you passing in '1,2,3' as a single string or are you passing a list of values from a multi-value parameter? If you are using a multi value parameter what you are trying to do should work, if you are passing a single string then you'll have to convert them to a table. There are plenty of examples of split functions for SQL Server 2008 if you do a quick search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SSRS will return @ID as a comma-separated list probably the best way is search by charindex like this:

```
select * from A 
Where charindex(','+cast(id as varchar(max))+',' , ','+@ID+',',1)>0
```