# SSRS selecting results based on comma delimited list with like statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Based on my question [SSRS selecting results based on comma delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464297/ssrs-selecting-results-based-on-comma-delimited-list)

Is it possible to do this, but instead of doing this as a an `EQUALS`, can it be done as below?
      `WHERE value like 'abc%','def%'`

One thing to note is that the `%` is not included in the list.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The question is entirely unclear, especially because the referenced question has no `EQUALS`.

Comment: `WHERE value like 'abc%' or value like 'def%'` should work

Comment: @MiguelH A list of comma separated values would be passed in so this wouldn't be possible

Comment: @peterbonar Split that into a temporary table/subquery, then `join` the main result set to that `on main.blah like tmp.split`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to split the passed in SSRS variable (CSV) into a table and join on that

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @tab (Col1)
VALUES (N'abc'),(N'def'),(N'xyz'),(N'nop'),(N'ghi'),(N'lmn')

DECLARE @substrings NVARCHAR(200) = 'abc,def,ghi'

;WITH cteX
AS(   --dynamically split the string
    SELECT Strings = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
    FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
        + REPLACE(@substrings, ',', '</i><i>') 
        + '</i>').query('.')
    ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
) 
SELECT
    T.*
FROM @tab   T
INNER JOIN cteX X ON X.Strings = T.Col1
```

gives the following result

[image]